# Collections of two-player free-form adventure ideas?

Tags: game-recommendation, published-adventures, one-on-one

I'm planning a short two-person (one PC, one GM) free-form session. Is there a good quality compilation of adventure outlines tuned for one-on-one play somewhere? The theme doesn't matter much, but I'd like some ideas fit for just one PC to get started.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread yet? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/a-2-player-rpg-for-buddies

Comment: @Ace: That thread seems to list many good games and systems. I'm more looking for plots and adventures.

Comment: Note this is not a request for game systems or random thoughts, but for "compilations of adventure outlines suitable for one-on-one play." @Oddysey's answer ignores the one-on-one restriction and the rest ignore the question's framing entirely (not to mention "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective").  Please don't get legitimate questions closed by filling them with crap answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It's not geared specifically towards two players, but [The Big List of RPG Plots](http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/blueroom/plots.htm) is my first stop in similar situations. *Any Old Port in the Storm,* *Don't Eat the Purple Ones,* *Recent Ruins,* and *Stalag 23* would all be fairly easy to set up, and well-suited for a single player to handle.

Comment: Granted, that's assuming that you don't want something more detailed and specific when you say "outline."

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore :(

Answer (score 6):

One of the best genres as a whole for this is Espionage and Spys... Steal liberally from every James Bond movie and book. And any other such story.

Another good one, surprisingly, is the "Rebel Scout" in both the Star Wars and US Civil War settings. The prominent NPC in both has to do with the PC's mode of transport... in SW, it's the astromech droid; in the USCW, one's horse. Sneaking into systems/towns, finding out if that loner there is friend or foe...

Related, but suitable for guest PC's as well, is the investigation based scenario. It works best when the character has a mission-based reason. But it allows stealing from just about 30-some odd TV shows.

Which leads to another resource or two for ideas:

- [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HomePage)
- [Interned Movie DataBase (IMDB)](http://imdb.com)

IMDB has plot synopses for many series' episodes. Steal liberally. Pick any series with a singular main character and rip away.

Answer (score 4):

If you've only got one player, ask them what kind of adventure they want.  If they don't have any ideas, ask them what books, movies, tv, and other media they enjoy, and shamelessly steal plots points to make something new.