# Easing Someone Into RPGs One-on-One

Tags: pathfinder-1e, one-on-one

I decided to get back into RPGs after a long hiatus and bought the Pathfinder Core Rulebook. My girlfriend picked it up and started reading it. Somewhat unexpectedly, she got really into it. She created a character and is eager to get started.

Eventually it'd be great to game together with a group, but I don't think she's quite ready yet (and neither of us know of any in-person games in the vicinity). She didn't grow up playing RPGs like me, so some of the concepts that I take for granted are entirely alien to her, and the sheer volume of rules is daunting.

Are there any resources for one-on-one Pathfinder games that'd make good entry points? I'm pretty rusty myself when it comes to DM'ing, so anything ready-made would be helpful.

Comment: A couple of ideas in this vein (broadly, not Pathfinder-specific): http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6739/list-of-two-player-free-form-adventure-ideas

Comment: Oh, here's a better one: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/homebrew-dd-with-only-2-players-plus-dm

Comment: Just a point to bear in mind when figuring out what will be good: your girlfriend's enthusiasm for getting started might be less to do with immersing herself in the world of Pathfinder and more to do with experiencing another side of you.  Be ready to recalibrate your expectations if needed.

Comment: To expand on Alticamelus' point, if that is the case, I would still take that as a "good thing" - in general, people need to learn from each other to make a relationship work, so at worst case she wants to learn more about YOU, best case she wants that AND to enjoy a new experience :D

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you can use any published module and just use techniques to downlevel it and/or have NPCs along, but if you want some published solo adventures for Pathfinder there are [a bunch available from Expeditious Retreat Press](http://paizo.com/store/byCompany/e/expeditiousRetreatPress/1On1AdventuresPFRPG). I have not played/run any but have read positive reviews.

Comment: Also available via PDF at http://e23.sjgames.com/search.html?gsys=1%20on%201%20Adventures