# Solo or 2 player adventures for 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, game-recommendation, published-adventures, one-on-one

I'm looking for solo or 2 player adventures for D&D 5e that I can play just with me and my wife. They can be free or paid, and from the publisher or indie. Ideally I'd like to play as well (in which case I might both play and DM) — I doubt it would be as fun to just have one DM and one player, but I don't want to dismiss the idea.

Does anyone know of any adventures like this, or know of any that can be easily adapted to 2 player for 5e?

Comment: It's a lot more fun than you might think. Here's a related question about exactly that aspect: [How do I keep me and my player happy in a one-on-one game?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19329)

Comment: Any can be adapted to a smaller party. The biggest issue is typically when adapting the big challenges (a dragon, for instance).

Comment: I just earned a badge for "Famous Question (question viewed more than 10,000 times)".  All 10,000 viewers should thank @SevenSidedDie for closing this question as not helpful

Comment: @ProfessorZ It's not that it's not useful, it's that it's off topic for this site. As the banner indicating the closure explains. Sorry! If it makes you feel better, I've now locked the page. It should stop bothering you now.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about D&D 5th edition is that you can readily use material for older editions by replacing the stats with their 5th edition version.

The best I currently know of are the One on One adventure series put out by [Expeditious Retreat Press](http://www.xrpshop.citymax.com/page/page/2561954.htm), originally written for D&D3e.

You can buy [them in PDF from RPGNow](http://www.rpgnow.com/browse.php?keywords=One%20on%20One%20adventures&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=).

There is a [compendium of the first eleven products](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/64278/One-on-One-Adventures-Compendium).