# Get started with RPGs

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, new-players

I don't know anything about RPGs, but I would like to start with Dungeons and Dragons. Where do I begin, what do I have to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  You'll be glad to know we already have an answer for this question, so how we work that here is close this question and link it over to the one with a bunch of answers already existing.  You may also want to read [What is role-playing and where do I start?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/what-is-role-playing-and-where-do-i-start?lq=1)

Comment: Hi MadTux, welcome to RPG.StackExchange! Please take a look at [About] and [FAQ].

Comment: Fast work @mxyzplk!