# Where Should I Start?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I'm looking to start playing D&D but I have never played so my knowledge is very limited. From what I can gather from reading about the different editions, I think I would prefer 1st or 2nd.
My question is where should I begin? 
It will take me awhile to learn the game and I have two friends interested in playing. I will be the DM.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)! Is there a particular reason why you're looking at 1st or 2nd edition?

Comment: I could swear this is a duplicate, but I'm having trouble finding it

Comment: I've closed this as too broad, as this question could cover multiple different books. If it's edited for a request for resources to read for a *specific* system, that's less bad, but as it's stands it's not a good fit for the site.

Comment: I don't know that it's too broad but it's not clear- I suspect it's a duplicate of either http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/what-is-role-playing-and-where-do-i-start?lq=1 or http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway or it's a game-rec question to recommend a game (http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28479/my-friends-and-i-are-new-to-rpgs-and-need-a-system-i-can-dm-and-they-can-pick-up) or a D&D edition http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13212/what-are-the-big-differences-between-the-dd-editions