# I have never played a role-playing game before. How do I start?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I'm really interested in playing role-playing games like D&D, but I don't know how to get into it. I have very few friends, and only 2 of them would probably even be interested in playing with me. (Also, one is moving away in the summer, and me and my other friend aren't really even that close.) How do I get started? Oh, and just in case this matters for some reason, I'm a 13 year old American boy.

Comment: Possibly of interest to you: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Can you look at the answers to the question at http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/what-is-role-playing-and-where-do-i-start?lq=1 and the question Dakeyras linked to, and see if they answer your question? If not, please edit this question to make it clearer how your question is different. We avoid having duplicate questions here, so that all answers for the same question are in he same place. :)

Comment: Closed as duplicate. If there are questions that you have *after* reading those questions, you're welcome to ask them.