# Wanting to play d&d but have no clue

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, pathfinder-beginner-box

So I've been highly interested in D&D through watching streams of it but unfortunately no one plays D&D anywhere close to me. I don't have a clue on how to make characters etc. So if anyone could help me then that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for this particular format, which is intended to provide a correct answer for a concrete, relatively objective question. You might consider asking at a message board/forum. If you'd like our advice, you could try breaking the question into smaller parts, like finding a group to play with or filling out a character sheet. It might help to take the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4457/4398) and edit yours to reflect how the answers you need are different from the answers it's asking for. If it gives you what you need, that's awesome and your question will probably be closed as a duplicate--not because it's bad, but because Stack Exchange likes to have all the answers to a particular question in one place so they're easier to find.

Comment: @BESW You really think we know what they're asking well enough to conclude that this is a duplicate? They already have been watching DnD streams, so they should already know the things in that question's answers. Seems like putting it on hold would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @DCShannon That's exactly what just happened; it's on hold until the querent clarifies what he's asking for. Yes, the reason for the hold could have been "unclear what you're asking" just as easily, but the result would be the same: a question on hold until edited for clarity so it can get useful answers. The reason for a close/hold does not influence the question's ability to get voted back open later.

Comment: I could help you with character creation, though this seems like something that one would do using the chat system. Is there a particular character concept you are aiming for? Or is there something with the character creation process that is confusing?

Comment: How is this question too broad? He needs a link to the Free D&D rules which explain how to do character creation, a link to the starter set so he can you know, learn how to start, and in the future, a link to the "How to Play" D&D videos. The answer is simple, and not really broad at all...

Comment: @GMNoob It's also tagged [pathfinder], so it's actually not obvious what the asker needs. It's both unclear and broad in its current form. Perhaps if it were clear, it would also be not too broad. We don't know.

Answer (score 0):

[The Swords & Wizardry Quick Start Rules](http://www.black-blade-publishing.com/Store/tabid/65/pid/24/Swords-Wizardry-Quick-Start-pdf-.aspx) were written for a retro clone of the original Dungeons & Dragons rules. But I think it is an excellent introduction to the type of adventures D&D and Pathfinder are best known for. And it is targeted to the novices. I had several local gamers use this to get the hang of Pathfinder. They went through the Quick Start and were a lot more comfortable in playing or referee a Pathfinder campaign.

The Quick Start assumes the reader is a complete novices and leads them through all the important elements of making characters and running D&D adventures. All of these concepts are applicable to Pathfinder the only difference is in the details of the rules themselves. The Pathfinder's beginners box will teach you that. The Quick Start will teach you how to tie it all together.