# Confused on role playing

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

I am new here and I am wanting to start my own vampire and werewolf roleplay game but I honestly don't know how role playing works. Can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: have you seen [what is role-playing, and how do I start](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4457/23970)? Also, I suggest you browse through the questions tagged [tag:new-player], as they have much accumulated wisdom.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! We already have answers to this question, so I've marked this one as a duplicate. I hope the existing page helps you. And welcome to one of the greatest hobbies in the world. :)