# What is this ? What is ""role-playing game" and which are the most famous/representative ones?

Tags: new-players

I arrived here following a totally irrelevant question/link.
What is this? What is "role-playing game"?.. I realise it is a "game" where people play some "role", but what does this mean? Which are the main characteristics that define a "role-playing game"? If there are many of them out there, which are the most famous (or representative) ones?

Comment: Hi Antonello! Welcome to the Stack! This question is very similar to the question here: [What is role-playing, and where do I start?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/what-is-role-playing-and-where-do-i-start). You should start there, and if you have more specific questions, you may have some luck in the [tag:new-players] or [tag:roleplaying] tags. You can also jump over to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) if you just want to talk to some of us.