# Where can I find the basic rules for D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, books

I’ve never played D&D before and I don’t know anyone who does. I want to get into it but I can’t figure out where to find the rules I need. Is there a free version of the rules that I can learn before I invest like $150 in the books?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your familiarity, these may be of use: [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/52137), [What is role-playing, and where do I start?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4457/52137). There's probably also a lot of useful questions between the linked and related there too.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE and to the hobby! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Trish “Recommend the material required to learn the rules of D&D” is worlds apart from “recommend me a cool D&D adventure”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Basic Rules* can be found [here](https://dnd.wizards.com/what-is-dnd/basic-rules) at the D&D website or [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) on D&D Beyond. Notably, the *Basic Rules* compendium at D&D Beyond contains the rules from the *Basic Rules* pdf as well as some additional material from the *Systems Reference Document*.

Comment: D&D Beyond's so-called "Basic Rules" are *not* the same as the actual *Basic Rules* document. Just look at the classes they contain; the *actual* Basic Rules contains only Cleric, Fighter, Rogue, and Wizard while D&D Beyond's "Basic Rules" contains all but Artificer. The top of D&D Beyond's Basic Rules states: "This section contains the Dungeons & Dragons Basic Rules and the rules in the SRD, released as part of the Open Gaming License.". D&D Beyond *calls* it the "Basic Rules" but it contains significantly more information than the *Basic Rules* document

Comment: I think an explanation of what the basic rules/srd contains, or more specifically don't contain, would be very useful. If you have the capacity, a primer for what to read to get started would be excellent, but that's arguably going above and beyond

Comment: @Someone_Evil Watching basketball tonight. My wife is a Chapel Hill grad. Might be able to put something together later though.