# Single Player Games

Tags: solo, game-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do solo, non-computer, RPG's exist, and if yes, which are good?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/792/do-solo-non-computer-rpgs-exist-and-if-yes-which-are-good)

Are there any single player RPGs?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/792/do-solo-non-computer-rpgs-exist-and-if-yes-which-are-good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not many! The options consist mainly of experimental indie RPGs and more traditional games from the 1980s.

On the indie end of the spectrum, there is Ewen Cluney's [Hikikomori](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://dsg.neko-machi.com/hikikomori.pdf), a 24-hour RPG (and hence unplaytested).

There is also Jackson Tegu's [The Smoke Dream](http://thesmokedream.wordpress.com/). I've played an earlier version of this, which didn't really work for me, but it's possible he's developed it since. It's an interesting concept, in which you deal yourself a maze of cards.

On the more traditional side, you might try Tunnels and Trolls, which has included solo versions since its early days. I remember [Buffalo Castle](http://www.flyingbuffalo.com/bcintro.htm) well: if you click on that link, you'll find an online version.

The recently relaunched [Maelstrom RPG](http://www.arion-games.com/maelstrom/maelstrom.html) also includes a solo adventure.

Finally, the 1980s [Fighting Fantasy gamebooks](http://www.fightingfantasy.com/) have found a new lease of life on the iPhone. And there is always, of course, [Choose Your Own Adventure](http://www.cyoa.com/).

Comment: I'd add beloved to the list: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gnPx8AlhF1TMarQ165Y1vGM382c6epUvCu1-HkXvICI/edit?hl=en&authkey=CJDYi58F&pli=1#

Comment: I would also include the [Mythic system](https://www.wordmillgames.com/mythic-rpg.html), which is designed for solo and GM-less roleplaying.