# looking for advice on miniatures and RPG

Tags: solo

can anybody offer any advice on what path to follow for solo playing games. I have been looking at different aspects of gaming. I have looked at a lot of board games and have recently bought Arkham horror which I play Solo, and will probably buy Mage Knight and a few others I have looked at on boardgamegeek.

I have friends who play 40K but I have been reading a lot of bad press from fans about games workshop so I am reluctant to get involved. I love the back story that comes with 40k though and have read several books. I like the miniatures side of games and would like to start painting at some point.

After reading a few blogs i have come across 'tunnels&trolls'"Darkcitygames' for solo playing RPG. but the obvious is D&D + Pathfinder. I have heard of party of one for pathfinder but not read any info for playing D&D solo.

So, I am a bit overwhelmed with all the information that I have gathered. I love boardgames so will probably still collect them, but its the world of RPG and Miniatures that I am seeking advice on. I have recently moved to Australia from the UK so I am not really part of a group except the 40k guys. I am thinking pathfinder party of may be the way forward. can anyone offer any advice.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/792/760

Comment: Welcome Andrew! Read our [help]. And a big hello from Sydney.

Comment: Thank you Brian for the warm welcome and the post to a previous question with relevant answers. I realise now that I was being vague. I have been sitting on the fence because I have never played an RPG game before. I think what I will do is buy some rule books and look into it that way.