# Single player RP/card games

Tags: solo

Are there single player RP or old-style card games that have an RP or old strategy adventure feel? I'm looking for something to play on my own, be it a game from the dark ages, a single-player card game, or a board game. I know about old RP books, which are fun but don't cut it for me as the temptation to cheat is too great.

Comment: You might be after this: [Looking for solo (one person) RPGs - do they exist?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/792/1204) (But... your post is unclear so I'm not certain.)