# Is there an rpg that is played on social media and can function without more than one dedicated player?

Tags: game-recommendation, online-roleplaying

This is extremely specific, but I'm looking for an rpg that is playable on social media and has the ability to support an amorphous group of people (strangers playing, people dropping in and out of the game, random people who aren't playing still providing prompts for those who are, etc). Basically, a 1 to N player game. So, not unrelated to [prior questions about one-player rpgs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/792/looking-for-solo-one-person-rpgs-do-they-exist), but not quite the same thing.

I'm indifferent as to whether it's a GM-less game or not, as long as it only needs 1 consistent player/GM/etc, though I have trouble imagining a game *with* a GM that is consistent with these requirements.

Vincent Baker's [Sundered Land: A Doomed Pilgrim](http://nightskygames.com/welcome/game/TheSunderedLand) is quite close to fitting the bill - as it is played by a group over google+ or some equivalent and people can drop in and out - but it still requires a minimum of either two dedicated active players or one plus a large group of desultory contributors. Are there any similar games that could support both group and solo play, or a mixture of the two?

Comment: By social media, do you mean small bits of text, or does video conferencing qualify since it's available on some social media platforms?

Comment: Hm, I'd say same answer as whether it's GMless - videoconferencing is allowed, as long as the game fulfills all other criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much this will be close to what you are searching for, but I follow a (hacked) 5E D&D show at [*itmeJP*'s Twitch channel](http://www.twitch.tv/itmeJP)  called ***The West Marches***, featuring a consistent GM and based off [*ars ludi*'s West Marches](http://arsludi.lamemage.com/index.php/78/grand-experiments-west-marches/).

Long story short, it's based of a permanent sandbox world where a rotating cast of players go on adventures, with a main central city where every adventure starts and ends.

I recently started a campaing based on a similar scenario with unexperiencied players, and it's working great.

Edit: as Miniman pointed out, I'll be more specific on how this might be something like what you are looking for. Of course, this answer is focused more on the "amorphous group" than on the "solo-play" part. As the article in ars ludi I linked earlier states:

> 1) There was no regular time: every session was scheduled by the players on the fly.
>
> 2) There was no regular party: each game had different players drawn
>   from a pool of around 10-14 people.
>
> 3) There was no regular plot: The players decided where to go and what to do.

1. Playable on social media: By using skype/Google+ Handouts and
   Roll20, a Web-based tabletop, it is played, streamed and recorded
   100% online.
2. Support an amorphous group of people: Each session, the group may be different. Maybe one week the group is bigger and the next smaller, some characters return when new ones appear. The only common things are the World and the GM, and the World is affected by what players did on previous sessions (You unleashed a plage on the forest? Well, maybe next session's group want to deal with that!)
3. Only needs 1 consistent player/GM/etc: As I said before, the only consistent player is the GM.

As of "Solo Play", that is something that doesn't mix well with group play. You could of course play on your own world, randomizing encounters, dungeons and so on, or importing modules from different places into your World to keep some fog on the future.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I edited the answer to explain myself better, I hope my suggestion is useful!

Comment: It's definitely improved!

Comment: You generally shouldn't include the "Edit:" in your edits. Just include the new information seamlessly.
(also, welcome to the site)

Comment: That's all really cool and quite close to fitting the bill - I'm still going to wait a bit and see if anyone finds something that supports a mixture of group and solo play better, but this looks nifty.